# Finding the next div with class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm creating multiple toggles, however, the toggle div's named "slide-tips" are sitting outside the div where the "toggle" is clicked. What I'm trying to do is find the next "slide-tips" and perform the toggle on that.

Original code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $content = $(".slide-tips").hide();
  $(".toggle").bind("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

I changed `$(this).next().slideToggle();` to `$(this).next().find('.slide-tips:first').slideToggle();` but no luck.

Html is as follows:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="toggle">Expand</div>
</div>
<div class="slide-tips">First tip content
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="toggle">Expand</div>
</div>
<div class="slide-tips">Second tip content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
$(this).parent().next(".slide-tips").slideToggle();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wzCA7/

Comment: Thank you! I was using parent as well but completely switched it around. Had `next().parent` - early Monday morning haha Thanks again